# convert AVspeechSynthsis utterance to aiff file or audio file and save to file

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, uilocalnotification, avspeechsynthesizer

How can i convert NSString into speech and save it to audio file?
I want to play that audio when an event occurs, with title of that event as a sound for Notifications.

I have tried following:

```
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

    NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"USER_NAME"];



    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@, it's time for %@",userName,self.eventNameLbl.text];

    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:string];
    [utterance setRate:AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

it convert to speech but cant save to file.